# How can I fix this “The following signatures were invalid…” error in Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, kali-linux

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo apt-get update         
[sudo] password for kali: 
Hit:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.i2p2.no unstable InRelease [19.7 kB]
Err:2 http://deb.i2p2.no unstable InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 67ECE5605BCF1346 I2P Debian Package Repository <killyourtv@i2pmail.org>
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://deb.i2p2.no/dists/unstable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: GPG error: http://deb.i2p2.no unstable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 67ECE5605BCF1346 I2P Debian Package Repository <killyourtv@i2pmail.org>
E: The repository 'http://deb.i2p2.no unstable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
and restart